# Binding a ViewModel property to a property of a static resource

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have an interface `IFooBar` and some concrete implementations of it, `FooBarOne` and `FooBarToo`.

```
public interface IFooBar
{
    int Value { get; set; }
}

public class FooBarOne : IFooBar { ... }

public class FooBarTwo : IFooBar { ... }
```

I've added a `DependencyProperty` (called `FooBar`) of type `IFooBar` to a custom control `MyControl`.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty FooBarProperty = ...

public IFooBar FooBar
{
  get { return (IFooBar)GetValue(FooBarProperty ); }
  set { SetValue(FooBarProperty, value); }
}
```

Whenever this control is used, I can create instances of `FooBarOne` or `FooBarTwo` as static resources, and then use these to set the `FooBar` `DependencyProperty` on instances of `MyControl` and this all works as expected.

```
  <UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <ns:FooBarOne x:Key="MyFooBarOne" Value="1"/>
      <ns:FooBarTwo x:Key="MyFooBarTwo" Value="2"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </UserControl.Resources>

  ...

  <controls:MyControl FooBar="{StaticResource MyFooBarOne}"/>
  <controls:MyControl FooBar="{StaticResource MyFooBarTwo}"/>
```

What I'm struggling with is that I now need to bind a value from a ViewModel to the the `IFooBar.Value` property.

I tried adding the following to my resouces:

```
  <UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <ns:FooBarOne x:Key="MyFooBarOne" Value="{Binding SomeViewModelProperty}"/>
      <ns:FooBarTwo x:Key="MyFooBarTwo" Value="{Binding SomeViewModelProperty}"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </UserControl.Resources>
```

But this doesn't work because `IFooBar.Value` isn't a `DependencyProperty`.

I realise I could probably add a new `DependencyProperty` for `IFooBar.Value` to my `MyControl`, but in reality `IFooBar` actually contains numerous properties and I wanted to avoid having to create a new `DependencyProperty` for each of the properties on `IFooBar`.

Is there a way for me to bind a ViewModel property onto the the properties of my `IFooBar` instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way for me to bind a ViewModel property onto the the properties of my `IFooBar` instances?

No, for you to be able to bind something *to* a property in XAML, the *target* property *must* be a dependency property.

In the below sample markup, `Value` is the target property and `SomeViewModelProperty` is the *source* property:

```
<ns:FooBarOne x:Key="MyFooBarOne" Value="{Binding SomeViewModelProperty}"/>
```

Again, the *target* property must be a dependency property for you to be able to *bind* a value to it.

Answer (score 1):

I presume that you're using MVVM, if so, then you should have properties on your ViewModel that return an IFooBar rather than declaring static resources.  Then you can just return those values.  If you need to specifically create an IFooBar for a given value, then you can create a ValueConverter that takes your value and spits out a FooBarOne or FooBarTwo.

Comment: Ideally I'd have IFooBar as a property on the ViewModel like you suggest.  Unfortunately the underlying architecture in this part of the application doesn't really allow this at the moment, leaving me to set these values from the View layer.  Maybe I should revisit the design.

Comment: That's why I suggested a ValueConverter too, you could then pass in the foobar type in the parameter (or one of your static resources)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification but I'm not quite sure I follow.  Can I still react to the VM property change and have this set on my IFooBar instance?  Any chance of a code snippet if you have time?